# VB.net (Excel) - Compile Error - Argument not Optional

Tags: vb.net

```
Function Schedule1(units1 As Double, rate1 As Double, totalunits1 As Double, month1 As Double, startmonth1 As Double) As Double

    If month1 <> Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(startmonth1, 0) Then
    'This IF statement fills the condition for duration of schedule and end of month
    ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(startmonth1, 0) < month1 And totalunits1 > units1 And (units1 - totalunits1) > rate1 Then
        Schedule1 = rate1
    ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(startmonth1, 0) < month1 And totalunits1 > units1 And (units1 - totalunits1) < rate1 Then
        Schedule1 = units1 - totalunits1
    'This IF statements fills the conditions for null months
    ElseIf totalunits1 = units1 Then
        Schedule1 = 0
    ElseIf month1 < Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(startmonth1, 0) Then
        Schedule1 = 0
    Else
    End If
End Function

Function Schedule2(units1 As Double, rate1 As Double, totalunits1 As Double, month1 As Double, startmonth1 As Double) As Double

    If month1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(startmonth1, 0) Then
    'This IF statements fills the condition for the start month
    ElseIf month1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(startmonth1, 0) And rate1 < units1 And month1 <> startmonth1 Then
        Schedule2 = rate1 * (startmonth1 - month1)
    ElseIf rate1 < units1 And month1 = startmonth1 Then
        Schedule2 = rate1
    ElseIf rate1 = units1 Or rate1 > units1 And month1 = startmonth1 Then
        Schedule2 = units1
    ElseIf rate1 >= units1 And month1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(startmonth1, 0) And startmonth1 <> month1 And (rate1 * (startmonth1 - month1)) > units1 Then
        Schedule2 = units1
    ElseIf rate1 >= units1 And month1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(startmonth1, 0) And startmonth1 <> month1 And (rate1 * (startmonth1 - month1)) < units1 Then
        Schedule2 = (rate1 * (startmonth1 - month1))
    ElseIf rate1 = units1 And startmonth1 = month1 Then
        Schedule2 = rate1
    Else
    End If
End Function

Function Schedule(units1 As Double, rate1 As Double, totalunits1 As Double, month1 As Double, startmonth1 As Double) As Double


    If month1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(startmonth1, 0) Then
        Schedule = Schedule2
    Else
        Schedule = Schedule1
    End If

End Function
```

So my last Function (schedule) is where I gt the compiling error. I'm trying to apply Schedule1 and Schedule2 functions into the Schedule function. What am I doing wrong here do to get this kind of error (my module is a different name)?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, could you please edit your question & insert the exact error message that you have received ? What have you done so far to solve it ?

Comment: When you call `Schedule1` or `Schedule2`, you need to provide all the arguments that those functions expect. For example `Schedule = Schedule2(units1, rate1, totalunits1, month1, startmonth1)`.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks it worked like a charm :)